# How to use output of inner query in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables in Oracle 11g database i.e. `EARNEDRATING` and `EMPLOYEE`.

```
EMP_NUM    RTG_CODE     EARNRTG_DATE
------------------------------------
101          CFI         18-Feb-98
101          CFII        15-Dec-05
101          INSTR       8-Nov-93
101          MEL         23-Jun-94
101          SEL         21-Apr-93


EMP_NUM EMP_LNAME   EMP_FNAME
-----------------------------
101     Kolmyoz      George
```

I want to write the query which find emp_num, emp_fname, emp_lname for all employee and their number of earned ratings.

I tried like this

```
select 
    er.emp_num, e.emp_fname, e.emp_lname, 
    count(er.rtg_code) as "Number of Earned Rating" 
from 
    earnedrating er 
join 
    employee e on er.emp_num=e.emp_num  
group by 
    er.emp_num;
```

but getting this error

> not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put in **group by** all the colums that are **not in** an aggregate function:

```
select er.emp_num,
       e.emp_fname,
       e.emp_lname,
       count(er.rtg_code) "Number of Earned Rating" 
from earnedrating er,employee e 
where er.emp_num = e.emp_num  
group by er.emp_num , e.emp_fname, e.emp_lname;
```

Answer (score 2):

Could be you need all column in group by

```
        select 
              er.emp_num
            , e.emp_fname
            , e.emp_lname
            , count(er.rtg_code)   "Number of Earned Rating" 
        from earnedrating er 
        join employee e on er.emp_num = e.emp_num  
        group by er.emp_num , e.emp_fname, e.emp_lname;
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use GROUP BY all field returned must either be in the group by clause or be used in an aggregate function. In your example, you can add the first name and last name to group by:

```
select er.emp_num
    , e.emp_fname
    , e.emp_lname
    , count(er.rtg_code) as "Number of Earned Rating" 
from earnedrating er 
    inner join employee e on er.emp_num=e.emp_num  
group by er.emp_num, e.emp_fname, e.emp_lname;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.emp_num, 
       e.emp_fname,
       e.emp_lname,
       s.rtg_code_count as "Number of Earned Rating" 
FROM (Select er.emp_num, 
             COUNT(er.rtg_code) as rtg_code_count 
      FROM earndrating er group by er.emp_num) as s,
     employee e 
WHERE s.emp_num=e.emp_num;
```